# Scala, suffix operator on implicit value type class

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, value-type

This code works fine for me.

```
object MyTest extends App {

  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  import scala.language.postfixOps


  implicit class Euro(val value: Double) extends AnyVal {
    def *(factor: Double): Euro = new Euro(value * factor)

    override def toString = s"$value EURO"

    def euro : Euro = this

  }


  def runMe = {
    val e1 = 100.0.euro
    println(e1)
  }

}
```

But `100.0.euro` is not so elegant, so I tried `100.0 euro` but this causes this error

> recursive value e1 needs type [error]     println(e1)

I think I'm breaking precedence or something like that. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This works: `val e1: Euro = 100.0`  Don't know if it's elegant enough.

Comment: Thanks @jwvh, I tried that too with success. But what I really want is type inference for è1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that is the reason why you have to explicitly enable postfixOps

compiler is probably trying to do something like

```
val e1 = 100.0.euro(println(e1))
```

you can avoid it by disambiguing where the line ends like this:

```
val e1 = 100.0 euro;
println(e1)
```

or

```
val e1 = (100.0 euro)
println(e1)
```

also empty line seems to work

```
val e1 = 100.0 euro

println(e1)
```

Comment: You can avoid this by explicitly placing a semicolon after `euro`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler try to use the println as a parameter to the euro method. Adding empty line before the println should solve it.

See about [suffix_notation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#suffix_notation).

Comment: The link to the style guide deserves a +1